# Automatic downloads in iTunes & App stores UPDATES on

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

In my iPhone 6 iTunes and App stores there is automatic downloads in which my Updates are on. Can I keep these Updates on or shall I turn off to prevent mobile data usage on roaming, or will these updates only happen on Wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a configurable option.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202180)

> You can also turn Automatic Downloads on or off over your cellular network on an iPhone or iPad Wi-Fi + Cellular. Go to Settings > [your name] > iTunes & App Store and turn Use Cellular Data on or off. Cellular Data downloads are limited to a file size of 150 MB or smaller.

[image]